# where is php exec() ffmpeg destination file location

Tags: php, ffmpeg

```
exec('ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i'.$_FILES['video']['tmp_name'].'  -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 thumbtest.jpg')
```

I am using the command to generate the thumbnail of the uploaded video. But could not locate the thumbnail where it is saved.Command is returning no error.

Comment: solved . I run the command after moving the temp file to a folder first. and there were path error.

Comment: Rather than posting as a comment, you might want to post it as an answer. In a day or two, you can click the checkmark next to it and get credit for answering your own question.

Answer (score 0):

finally solved . I run the command after moving the temp file to a folder first. and there were path errors. –